# Looping through CSS element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to use jQuery's `.css('width', '0%')` and loop through it to extend it to 100% using a JavaScript loop?

```js
// Flashing function
fadeloop('.name-part.p', 1500, 500, true)
fadeloop('.name-part.y', 900, 300, true)
fadeloop('.name-part.x', 1000, 3200, true)
fadeloop('.name-part.i', 800, 2200, true)
fadeloop('.name-part.s', 200, 1400, true)

function fadeloop(el,timeout,timein,loop){
    var $el = $(el),intId,fn = function(){
         $el.fadeOut(timeout).fadeIn(timein);
    };
    fn();
    if(loop){
        intId = setInterval(fn,timeout+timein+100);
        return intId;
    }
    return false;
}

// Loop from 0% width to 100% width

$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.name-home').css('width', '0%');
})
```

```css
.name-home {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 754px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Can provide a link if interested.

Comment: why exactly would you want to do this? you could just you css directly to transition from one width to another in a given amount of time

Comment: If you show us (or explain as clearly as possible) what kind of effect you're attempting to create, that would help us understand what's going wrong.

Comment: @philr I'm an idiot for not thinking about using `@keyframes`. Could I potentially do `@keyframes { from {width: 0%} to {width: 100%}}` and then use `animation: animation 5s;`?

Comment: unless you need keyframes for a specific reason over `transition` i'd use `transition` here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/nt0ahqjr/3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the effect you're looking for, but I believe CSS animations are really the way to go. Here's a fairly smooth 'flexing'/'breathing' effect:

```css
#wrapper { text-align: center }
.name-home {
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
@keyframes anim {
  from { width:0% }
  to { width:20% }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"
><span class="name-home p">p</span
><span class="name-home y">y</span
><span class="name-home x">x</span
><span class="name-home i">i</span
><span class="name-home s">s</span
></div>
```

Or perhaps this is closer to what you're trying to achieve.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.name-home {
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.name-home.p {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: anim-py;
}
@keyframes anim-py {
  from { width:0% }
  75% { width:100% }
  to { width:0% }
}
.name-home.y {
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
  animation-name: anim-py;
}
.name-home.x {
  animation-duration: 4.2s;
  animation-name: anim-xs;
}
@keyframes anim-xs {
  from { width:0% }
  75% { width:100% }
  to { width:0% }
}
.name-home.i {
  animation-duration: 2.4s;
  animation-name: anim-i;
}
@keyframes anim-i {
  from { width:0% }
  75% { width:100% }
  to { width:0% }
}
.name-home.s {
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
  animation-name: anim-xs;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"
><div class="name-home p">p</div
><div class="name-home y">y</div
><div class="name-home x">x</div
><div class="name-home i">i</div
><div class="name-home s">s</div
></div>
```